# rpm name gets changed after installation

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have created rpm with following name:

```
[root@buildbtl ship-rpms]# ls
cdd-pcts-5.1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I installed rpm with the command

```
rpm -ivh cdd-pcts-5.1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

After querying the installed package the name gets changed to
`cdd-pcts-5.1.1-.el6.x86_64`

```
[root@buildbtl ship-rpms]# rpm -qa | grep cdd-p
cdd-pcts-5.1.1-.el6.x86_64
```

I cannot understand why extra `-` is added after version 5.1.1

How can I maintain the name of the created rpm and installed rpm as same.
In the spec file I have overridden the MACRO `_build_name_fmt` for naming the rpm
using the command below:

```
%define _build_name_fmt %{NAME}-%{_VERSION}%{Release}.%{ARCH}.rpm
```

Thanks in advance for guidance

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how would you rename rpm package file (in your case via changing definition of `_build_name_fmt`), it's actual package name (which rpm database actually cares about) is always stored inside the package along other rpm metadata. This means that the easiest way to ensure that name of rpm package is the same both in rpm database and in rpm build filename is to not change the `_build_name_fmt`.

Answer (score 0):

The RPM database always stores four *"metadata"* fields which identify the package: *name*, *version*, *release* and *arch* (architecture).  It gets this information by reading the contents of the RPM file; its filename is irrelevant.  There are additional metadata fields for RPMs which you can see using the `rpm -qi`*package* command (see *[The Parts of an RPM Query](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html#S3-RPM-QUERY-I-OPTION)* for more information).

In your example, it appears that

- *name* is `"cdd-pcts"`,
- *version* is `"5.1.1"`,
- *release* is `".el6'`, and
- *arch* is `"x86_64"`

The default format for displaying this information is *name*-*version*-*release*.*arch*, which puts a "-" immediately before the *release* ".el6".  Perhaps `%{Release}` is built up from two symbols, and in modifying the spec-file you made one of those symbols empty.

Before installing, you can also inspect your package to check if the metadata is set correctly, e.g.,

```
rpm -qip cdd-pcts-5.1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i a m using release macro as Release:  {?dist}. yes agreed that i am not appending the release number to it like it should be Release: %{rel}%{?dist}. one question here is can i override _build_name_fmt to get the rpm  name (cdd-pcts-5.1.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) same as installed rpm name ie listed in rpm packages using rpm -qa command